Reuse same kafka topic as GlobalKTable and KStream
I have specific request, there are 2 topics:
Cards - frequently changed, lots of data
Artworks - rarely changed, small
Cards have FK to artwork to get artworkName and both of those entities are later tables in database cause I need separate artworks too.
I use Apache Kafka Streams to process data, joining Cards KStream records with Artwork GlobalKTable.

// Registering the topic as KTable
GlobalKTable<ArtworkKeyRecord, ArtworkDataRecord> artWorkTable = streamsBuilder.globalTable(
        "ARTWORK_TOPIC",
        Consumed.with(artworkKeyInSerdes, artworkInSerdes),
        Materialized.<ArtworkKeyRecord, ArtworkDataRecord, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("artWorkStore")
                .withKeySerde(artworkKeyInSerdes)
                .withValueSerde(artworkInSerdes)
);

//Registering Stream for cards
KStream<CardKeyRecord, CardDataRecord> cardStream =
        streamsBuilder.stream("CARD_TOPIC", Consumed.with(cardKeyInSerdes, cardInSerdes));

StreamExceptionCatcher.check("CardProcessor", cardStream.process(() -> new CardProcessor(cardMapper)))
                .to("CARD_OUT_TOPIC", Produced.with(cardKeyInSerdes, cardDataOutSerdes));

...

public class CardProcessor implements Processor<CardKeyRecord,
        CardDataRecord,
        CardKeyRecord,
        MayBeException<FullCardData, FullCardData>> {
...
public void process(Record<KeyRecord, DataRecord> record) {
    final Data data = record.value().getData();
    ArtworkKeyRecord artKey = ArtworkKeyRecord(data.getFKARTWRKID());
    ValueAndTimestamp<ArtworkDataRecord> valueAndTimestamp = this.artWorkStore.get(artKey);

    if (valueAndTimestamp != null) {
        ArtworkDataRecord artwork = valueAndTimestamp.value();
        log.debug("Found artwork for key: {} with value: {}", artKey, artwork);
        CardData cardData = cardMapper.toData(record.value(), artwork); //here map specific fields
        this.context.forward(new Record<>(
                record.key(),
                MayBeException.of(cardData),
                record.timestamp(),
                record.headers()));
    } else {
        log.debug("Skip message: Card({})", record.value().getData().getCARDID());
    }
      
}
...
}

How can I do so new messages in Artwork topic both update GlobalKTable and being pushed to the next topic to be consumed by connector into database?
Cause I can't reuse topic in topology and don't understand how to correctly handle artworks then..

Why do you need a GlobalKTable ? Can you use a KTable instead ? Kafka-streams supports foreign key join on KTable
